# Show that f:[a,∞)→R for some a>0, and defined by $f(x)=1/\sqrt(x)$, is Lipschitz continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Here is my attempt:
$$|\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt a}|=\frac{|\sqrt a-\sqrt x|}{\sqrt xa}=\frac{|a-x|}{a\sqrt x + x\sqrt a}.$$

I want to show that $\dfrac{|a-x|}{a\sqrt x + x\sqrt a}\leq L|x-a|, $  which implies
$\dfrac{1}{a\sqrt x + x\sqrt a}\leq L.$

So, what can i do to find a L ?

Comment: Can you prove that its derivative is bounded ?

Comment: no... i cant use derivative

Comment: Can the downvote? I don't understand. The OP is showing his effort at work, (+1).

Comment: Is the fraction decreasing? I.e. if $x\leq y$ is $\frac{1}{a\sqrt{y} + y\sqrt{a}} \leq \frac{1}{a\sqrt{x} + x\sqrt{a}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous if there exists a constant $C$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant C|x-y|$$
Hence, just notice that
$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{a}}\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{x})}|x-a|\leqslant \frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}|x-a|.$$
done.

Comment: it should be a^(3/2), right?

Comment: I corrected @GusBr

Comment: i got it, thanks!